# Até que ponto é interessante usar o APC? É recomendável usá-lo com objetos?

Tags: php, apc, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho lido sobre o cache de opcode do PHP, o APC. A maioria dos materiais que achei para ler, apesar de bons, somente explicam a instalação/utilização das funções do APC.

O que gostaria de saber é:

- Até que ponto é interessante usar o APC?
- É recomendável usar o APC com objetos?

Exemplo:

```
<?php
class Test
{
    private $someAttribute;

    public function __construct( $someAttribute )
    {
        $this->someAttribute = $someAttribute;
    }

    public function getSomeAttribute()
    {
        return $this->someAttribute;
    }
}

if ( !apc_exists( 'test' ) ) {
    $data = new Test( 'testing...' );
    apc_add( 'test', $data, 120 );
} else {
    $data = apc_fetch( 'test' );
}
```

Imaginando que eu possa criar mais de uma instancia do meu objeto, como por exemplo, para persistir os dados em métodos de `update()`, `insert()`, etc,
isso "mataria" a ideia do cache neste exemplo?

Estou confuso com a utilização do APC;

Comment: Esqueça o APC. Ele não terá suporte no php 5.5. triste fim, mas realidade. Se estiver procurando por alternatives, tente o [xcache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/) e [eacelerator](http://eaccelerator.net/).

Comment: A APC não vai morrer com o PHP 5.5. Simplesmente a partir dessa versão haverá nativamente outro método de *opcode caching*, a do Zend Optimizer+, integrando o core da linguagem. É quase o mesmo que aconteceu com a PDO que de uma biblioteca/módulo à parte foi integrada ao 5.3 sendo facultado-se apenas seus drivers.

Comment: Sim eu sei, mas funções com chamadas específicas a funções do apc como _apc_store()_ serão descontinuadas, então quem as tiver tem de refatorar o código migrando para o equivalente em zend optimizer, começar um código agora com apc não seria uma boa

Comment: De fato, mas todo programador deve ficar sempre de olho no changelog. Programadores que hospedam as aplicações em servidores compartilhados até tem um tempo bem maior pra se adaptar dada a vergonhosa velocidade com que as versões são atualizadas por aqui. E talvez eu esteja falando besteira mas me parece que esse opcode será nativo, nativo mesmo, sem ser necessário que programador faça nada.

Answer (score 8):

Existem alguns conceitos que deve entender sobre a utilização de cache no PHP que ajudaram a identificar as vantagens de cada uma das possibilidades.

**Tipos de cache**

- Arquivos
- Banco de dados
- Memória compartilhada
- Memória RAM
- Objetos e variáveis
- Opcode

**Arquivos**

O cache de arquivos é usado em casos que um processamento sempre gera um mesmo resultado. O cache é gerado toda vez que há uma atualização, e o sistema irá verificar a existência do cache evitando processamento desnecessário.

Esse tipo de cache é usado em miniaturas de fotos, páginas com dados guardados em banco de dados, mas que não são atualizados constantemente como blogs, etc.

**Banco de dados**

O cache de banco de dados pode ser feitas de várias maneiras, uma delas é pelo próprio `SGBD`. É usado quando uma consulta no banco é realizada muitas vezes e o resultado trás uma quantidade considerável de registros.

Um exemplo de utilização no MySQL é a utilização do comando SQL_CACHE

Substituindo uma query como

```
SELECT id, item, valor FROM vendas WHERE id > 0;
```

Para

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE id, item, valor FROM vendas WHERE id > 0;
```

Obs.: Esta é apenas umas das maneiras.

**Memória compartilhada**

É a possibilidade compartilhar os dados em memória com vários processos em execução, facilitando assim que um dado já processado não necessite de ser processado novamente por outro processo.

**RAM Disk**

Muitas vezes o SO faz mal uso da memória RAM, utilizando apenas uma parte da existente deixando a outra parte parada. Sendo assim, é possível utilizar essa memória "parada" como meio de armazenamento criando discos virtuais. Estes discos possuem velocidade de leitura e escrita muito superior por ser memória primária. O que torna o acesso às informações de 50 a 300 vezes mais rápida do que a leitura em um HD.

**Objetos e variáveis**

O cache de objetos e variáveis tambem possuem várias maneiras de serem feitas. Pode ser por meio de serialização em arquivos, armazenamento em memória seja no servidor ou mesmo no cliente, etc.

A utilização de cache de objetos e variáveis requer cuidado com a confiabilidade e precisão dos dados armazenados. Se os objetos podem ter parâmetros atualizados, procure uma forma consistente de mater o cache atualizado tambem.

Para manter o cache atualizado, utilize chaves não redundantes, que tornem fácil a identificação de um objeto. Isso possibilita que métodos `update` ou `insert` possam deletar e readicionar no cache, ou apenas sobrescrever dependendo do sistema de cache adotado.

Armazenar objetos inteiros em cache pode gerar problemas por guardar não apenas informações, mas tudo sobre o objeto. Você pode utilizar métodos como serialização de objetos utilizando  os métodos mágicos [`__sleep` e `__wakeup`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php) para guardar apenas os atributos do objeto. Ao adicionar no cache, utilize a funcão `serialize()` para obter a string do objeto, e `unserialize()` para obter a instancia do objeto atráves de uma string serializada.

**Opcode**

Toda vez que um script PHP é executado o interpretador irá compilar em um código que a máquina seja capaz de entender. O resultado é um bytecode chamado opcode (Código de operação). Em toda a requisição o arquivo do PHP é compilado.

Agora imagine a situação de um aplicativo feito em uma framework muito grande, que realiza vários processos até chegar ao fim da requisição. Serão vários arquivos compilados a toda requisição para uma tarefa muitas vezes simples.

**Memcache e APC**

O Memcache e o APC possibilitam a criação de cache em memória primária para armazenar vários tipos de dados, como variáveis, objetos, dados de sessão, thumbnails de fotos etc. Permite a criação de cache em servidores distribuídos, mas não possui cache de Opcode.

[Material sobre Memcache 01](http://www.objectzilla.com.br/2009/05/02/ja-usou-memcached.html)

O APC possui os mesmos recursos do memcache, porem não tem suporte a servidores distribuidos, e possibilita a utilização de cache de Opcode.

[Material sobre APC](http://www.douglaspasqua.com/2011/09/15/usando-apc-alternative-php-cache/)

A aplicação de cada um pode variar de acordo com a aplicação ou servidor.

Uma observação do seu código, é no lugar de `apc_add` usar `apc_store`, pois o `apc_add` apenas adiciona, enquanto o `apc_store` sobrescreve caso a chave já exista.

[Script para comparar a velocidade entre os aceleradores](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/09/cache-performance-comparison/)

[Lista de "aceleradores" para PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators)

Answer (score 0):

O APC apenas vai criar um cache em memória local, ou seja, se o seu site expandir e precisar de ter vários servidores, o cache de um servidor não vai ser enxergado por outros servidores.

Nesse caso talvez seja melhor usar memcached ou mesmo MySQL com tabelas tipo HEAP. O problema desta solução é que consome memória RAM que se tiver de guarda muitos dados pode fazer falta nos servidores. Para além disso, se tiver de reiniciar o servidor memcached ou MySQL, os dados armazenados em RAM se perdem.

Nesse caso pode usar Redis que armazena também em disco. No entanto, se já estivet usando MySQL 5.6 ou compatível, esta versão já oferece interface compatível memcached para dados armazenados em tabelas INNODB. Nesse caso é o mais recomendável.

Comentamos sobre isso no ano passado no podcast [Lately in PHP 32](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/200--Zend-Optimizer-Cache-in-PHP-55-and-MySQL-56-Performance-Improvements--Lately-in-PHP-podcast-episode-32.html)